# Filter Dictionary with a case insensitive search

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

This is a follow-up question on How to [Filter a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657895/how-to-filter-a-dictionary) only I need the filter to be **case-insensitive**

I have a dictionary that populates a Pickerview in Swift 3.

```
var facilityDict:       [Int: [String: String]] = [:]
```

> 17: ["id": "199", "facilitycode": "036", "location_name": "Centerpoint
>   Medical Offices"],
>   41: ["id": "223", "facilitycode": "162",
>   "location_name": "Dark Ridge Medical Center"],
>   14: ["id": "196",
>   "facilitycode": "023", "location_name": "Spinnerpark"],
>   20: ["id":
>   "202", "facilitycode": "048", "location_name": "Educational Theater"],
>   30: ["id": "212", "facilitycode": "090", "location_name": "Partner
>   Medical   Offices"],
>   49: ["id": "231", "facilitycode": "223",
>   "location_name": "GreenBay   Administrative Offices"]

The Dictionary is quite long.  I have a `Textbox` that fires when data is changed and I use this to create a search variable.  If someone types in "ar", I want to filter every thing in the dictionary that has the characters "ar" in it so that I can reset the Picker list with a much smaller subsection of the original Big Dictionary list.

The filter
`let filteredDictionaries = facilityDict.filter{$0.value.contains(where: {$0.value.contains("ar")})}.map{$0.value}`
seems to filter the dictionary well, However I need the search to be case-insensitive. Are there options I can set to change the filter show to case insensitive?

Comment: Got it. So in this example it would be `let filteredDict = self.sharedDataVal.departmentDict.filter{$0.value.contains(where: {($0.value.range(of: srchval, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil)})}.map{$0.value}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contains method it is the same as `range(of: "String") != nil` without any options. All you need is to use range of String != nil with caseInsensitive options:

```
extension String {
    func contains(_ string: String, options: CompareOptions) -> Bool {
        return range(of: string, options: options) != nil
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
"whatever".contains("ER", options: .caseInsensitive)
```

If you need to create a dictionary from your array of dictionaries, you would need to use forEach to iterate through the result and rebuild your dictionary from it:

---

```
let facilityDict: [Int: [String: String]] = [
    17: ["id": "199", "facilitycode": "036", "location_name": "Centerpoint Medical Offices"],
    41: ["id": "223", "facilitycode": "162", "location_name": "Dark Ridge Medical Center"],
    14: ["id": "196", "facilitycode": "023", "location_name": "Spinnerpark"],
    20: ["id": "202", "facilitycode": "048", "location_name": "Educational Theater"],
    30: ["id": "212", "facilitycode": "090", "location_name": "Partner Medical Offices"],
    49: ["id": "231", "facilitycode": "223", "location_name": "GreenBay Administrative Offices"]]

var filtered: [Int: [String: String]] =  [:]

facilityDict.filter{$0.value.contains{$0.value.contains("AR", options: .caseInsensitive)}}.forEach{filtered[$0.key] = $0.value}

print(filtered)  // [30: ["id": "212", "facilitycode": "090", "location_name": "Partner Medical Offices"], 41: ["id": "223", "facilitycode": "162", "location_name": "Dark Ridge Medical Center"], 14: ["id": "196", "facilitycode": "023", "location_name": "Spinnerpark"]]
```

Comment: Leo, Filter works well. however the result is [[String: String]].  I need the result back into [Int: [String: String]].  Any suggestions?

Comment: I am getting an "Extra argument 'options' in cell" error on the .caseInsensitive.  I also notice the contains will match any "AR" in the above example.  What if I need it to match something explicit like an entry "AR Medical Center" and not match the "Spinnerpark" entry?  Thanks for the protocol hints!!! New to this.

Comment: Leo, I have an additional concern where I am using this filter on slightly different data, and the filter is matching the right data only I am getting duplicate values.  Should I open this as a different question?