# String extension giving extra argument error

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string extension from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753552/filter-dictionary-with-a-case-insensitive-search) that seems pretty straightforward only I am getting an extra argument error.
**Variable**

```
var modelDict: [Int: [String: String]] = [:]
```

**Extension:**

```
import Foundation


extension String {
    func contains(_ string: String, options: String.CompareOptions) -> Bool {
        return range(of: string, options: options) != nil
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let filteredDict = self.sharedDataVal.modelDict.contains(manufacturerCodeVar, options: .caseInsensitive)

print("Filtered Array \(filteredDict)")
```

Any idea why .caseInsensitive is flagged as an extra arg?

**Edited** based on Rob's suggestion, but I don't think I am getting it yet.

**Variable Def:**

```
class sharedData {

    static let sharedInstance = sharedData()
    struct model{
        var id: String
        var modelName: String
        var modelNumber: String
        var manuShort: String
        var phiTypeCode: String
        var phiTypeDescription: String
    }

    var modelDictTest:          [Int: [model]] = [:]
}
```

**Loading the Dictionary:**

```
    let modelID              = recordInfo["id"] as? String
    let modelName            = recordInfo["modelname"] as? String
    let modelNumber          = recordInfo["modelnumber"]as? String
    let modelManuShort       = recordInfo["manu_short"]as? String
    let modelPhiTypeCode     = recordInfo["phitypecode"]as? String
    let modelPhiDescription  = recordInfo["phitypedescription"]as? String

    let localModelDict = sharedData.model(id: modelID!, modelName: modelName!, modelNumber: modelNumber!, manuShort: modelManuShort!, phiTypeCode: modelPhiTypeCode!, phiTypeDescription: modelPhiDescription!)
```

**Usage:**

```
let filteredDict = self.sharedDataVal.modelDictTest.contains(manufacturerCodeVar, options: .caseInsensitive)
```

Still getting the same error, but I am sure I am not grasping loading a Struct int `modelDictTest` correctly

Comment: What type is `modelDict`?

Comment: I'm guessing `modelDict` is an Array, thus your not calling your `contains` method but the Array one, which takes only one argument.

Comment: Unless your `modelDict` is not String, you can not use `contains` method.

Comment: Good point. I forgot to show that Dictionary: 
    var modelDict:          [Int: [String: String]] = [:]

Comment: What is the `Int` in `[Int: [model]]`? What is `manufacturerCodeVar`? What do you expect `filteredDict` to be (remember, `contains` just returns a Bool, not a dictionary). What *is* a "model" in your case? You have a lot of confusing abbreviations here (`phi`, `manu`) that make it very hard to explore the underlying problem you're trying to solve. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Create a small piece of code, that can run in a playground, and shows what you want the input to be, and the output to be. This looks very simple, if you're able to focus on what you're solving.

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your classes and structures starting with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 3):

`modelDict` is of type `[Int: [String: String]]`. You've written an extension on `String`. That's not related.

Instead, you're getting the standard `contains(_:)` from `Sequence`, which has no `options` parameter.

As a general rule, if you have a type like `[Int: [String: String]]` and you find yourself wanting to create extensions for that type, you really meant to make `model` a struct that *has* an `[Int: [String: String]]`. Then you can just add methods to it, and don't need extensions.

Comment: makes sense.  As you can see, I am fairly new to this =). Would you happen to have an example or point me to an example to a struct for this type of Dictionary. `modelDic` is defined as a globally shared variable and does not sit in the class where I I am trying to use the filter BTW.

Comment: This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6UOrwS-Tg&feature=youtu.be The main point is to just make your model its own type (a struct or class). Then add methods to it that you need. Internally it may have a dictionary like your current `modelDict`, but the callers don't have to care about that. You can just create a `contains(_:options:)` method for your `Model` type, and if it can do whatever it needs with its internal dictionary.

Comment: Made an attempt in my edited problem above.  Don't think I am getting it. =/