# searching with special characters

Tags: swift, search, character

New to swift and programming in general.  I have this searchBar function which searches for what is entered and tableView contents.  I noticed it's not working for special characters.  Ex: I have a tableView where Hon's is the name of the text.  When I type Hon on the search bar, Hon's appear on the list of the tableView.  However, when I type Hon's (with the apostrophe s), the tableView lists all the contents and it's not searching it properly.  I expect that only Hon's should appear.  How do I fix the code below?

```
public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredData = all.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if filteredData.count == 0 {
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = true
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting to NSString? range(of: String) expects a String and `return range != nil`

Comment: btw you can simplify your condition to a single line `searchActive = !filteredData.isEmpty`

Comment: an your filteredData can be simplified as `filteredData = all.filter { $0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }` or use this custom extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753828/2303865

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for the comments but it's still showing all results when I type in Hon's in the search Bar.

Comment: Then may br you have to debug table view data source methoda

Comment: @ms_abc don't forget to set the delegate UISearchBarDelegate https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar

Comment: Make sure that method is being called

Comment: Hi there, yes I have set the delegate but still having problems.  Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let text = "Hon's Shop"
let searchText = "Hon's"//works for "Hon" also
let found = text.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())//returns true
```

So you can modify your filter as:

```
filteredData = all.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
   return text.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
})
```

---

**Update**
As Leo mentioned, you can only change return statement to:

```
return range != nil
```

But using my suggestion you can shorten code!

Comment: Hi D4ttatraya, thanks for the comments but it's still showing all results when I type in Hon's in the search Bar.