# Swift 4 Struct Searching by parameter with contains

Tags: arrays, swift, search, struct, predicate

I have array of structs and I don't know really how to use search by one of the struct's parameter.

My struct looks like:

```
struct Actor {
   var name: String!
   var posterURL: String!

    init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
       name = dictionary["name"] as! String
       posterURL = dictionary["image"] as! String
    }
}
```

So, I've tried to use predicate

```
let actorSearchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", text)
filterredActors = (actors as NSArray).filtered(using: actorSearchPredicate)
```

But, when I'm trying to type anything, it crashes with error

```
[<_SwiftValue 0x10657ffb0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
```

What is the right way of using predicate search with structs? 
Thank you

Comment: CHeck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762460/swift-4-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant/44790231

Comment: Why bother with `NSPredicate`? `actors.filtered{ $0.name.contains(text) }`

Comment: Only thing missing with `$0.name.contains(text)` is making it case insensitive.

Comment: One really easy way of making it case insensitive is `$0.name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())`.

Comment: @creeperspeak filterredActors = actors.filter{($0 as AnyObject).name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())}   
I did like this, but it continues crushing

Comment: Why are you casting as `AnyObject`?  You shouldn't be using that at all in Swift 4.  Try `actors.filtered{( $0.name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) )}`.  Also, there is a difference between `filter` and `filtered`.  Make sure you're using `filtered`.

Comment: @creeperspeak better to use caseInsensitiveCompare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329568/check-if-a-string-exists-in-an-array-case-insensitively/31330465?s=2|54.9670#31330465 or you can create your own caseInsensitiveContains https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753828/2303865

Comment: @Vitalyz123 You should avoid as much as possible the use of implicitly unwrapped optionals and make your properties constants `let name: String` and naming a string URL is misleading, change its type to a real URL

Comment: @creeperspeak thanks, it worked but with this way
"filterredActors = actors.filter{( $0.name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) )}." What is the difference between 'filter' and 'filtered' ? Swift only offers 'filter' option

Comment: Sorry - I got it mixed up with the difference between `sort` and `sorted`.

Answer (score 3):

`NSPredicate` is not needed, Swift got convenience methods to check ***case insensitive***

> *[whether the receiver contains a given string by performing a case insensitive, locale-aware search.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923385-localizedcaseinsensitivecontains)*

```
filterredActors = actors.filter { $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(text) }
```

and ***case and diacritic insensitive***

> *[whether the receiver contains a given string by performing a case and diacritic insensitive, locale-aware search.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923402-localizedstandardcontains)*

```
filterredActors = actors.filter { $0.name.localizedStandardContains(text) }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use a predicate to filter structs, you can do it without going into `@objc` territory or converting your data into `NSArray`:

```
func filter(actors: [Actor], named: String) -> [Actor] {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains[cd] %@", named)
    return actors.filter {
        predicate.evaluate(with: $0.name)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
struct Actor {
    let name: String
    let imdb: String
}

let actors = [
    Actor(name: "John Travolta", imdb: "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000237"),
    Actor(name: "Uma Thurman", imdb: "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000235"),
    Actor(name: "Samuel L. Jackson", imdb: "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000 168"),
    Actor(name: "Penélope Cruz", imdb: "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0004851"),
    Actor(name: "Penelope Ann Miller", imdb: "http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000542")
]

print(filter(actors: actors, named: "Uma").map { $0.name })
// ["Uma Thurman"]
print(filter(actors: actors, named: "J").map { $0.name })
// ["John Travolta", "Samuel L. Jackson"]
```

Filtering using a predicate is useful, for example, to take into account diacritics. Let's search an actor name with an accented character:

```
print(filter(actors: actors, named: "Penelope").map { $0.name })
// ["Penélope Cruz", "Penelope Ann Miller"]
```

It finds both "Penelope", with and without accented "e".

Using `String.contains` won't work in that case:

```
let text = "Penelope"
let hits = actors.filter { ( $0.name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) )}
print(hits.map { $0.name })
// ["Penelope Ann Miller"]
```

There are better alternatives (`String` localized search, regular expressions, `String.range(of:options:range:locale)`, ...). Using predicates is not faster (not much slower either). It may be easier to reason about complex queries using predicate syntax if you already know it.